# Книга по С++ НЕ для чайника

Tags: c++, книги

До этого кодил на php, знаю mysql,html,js. Понимаю алгоритмы, мозг повернут правильно и сонаправлен с руками) Нужна книга для обучения C++, без разжевывания и воды но и не сильно крутая, желатьно что бы было в ней побольше примеров. Посоветуйте что-нибудь. Язык: ENG/RUS.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот ещё ссылки на один интересный блог:

[Книги для начинающих](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2006/09/blog-post_19.html)

[Книги для продолжающих](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2006/09/c.html)

Да и вообще блог на мой взгляд весьма интересен, рекомендую к ознакомлению.

Comment: для полноты списка надо было, кроме книг для начинающих и продолжающих дать еще книги для законченных)))

Comment: Очень хорошие ссылки (кстати, обе на один ресурс). Обсуждение книг там мне больше всего понравилось.

Answer (score 5):

1. С. Липпманн - C++ для начинающих (3-е изд.) (книга очень обхъемная, и, несмотря на название, отнюдь не для чайников)
2. Б. Страуструп - Язык программирования C++ (вообще самая что ни есть классическая классика, хотя, считается, что Страуструп пишет скучновато и академично)
3. Б. Страуструп - Программирование. Принципы и практика использования C++
4. Б. Страуструп - Дизайн и эволюция C++
5. Б. Эккель - Философия С++
6. Плюс еще 100500 книг Мейерса и Саттера

А вообще, имхо, зря вы с php начинали

Comment: Это не комментарий, а вопрос в тему ко всем.

Никто не встречал небольшого (скажем до 300 страниц), но достаточно полного справочника по С++? 

Желательно не слишком формальное описание с фрагментарным примерами. Что-то для хорошо знающих Си и что-то читавших по С++.

**Вообще, такое возможно?**

--

Я помню  был справочник по Си карманного формата, страниц на 100, даже с кратким описанием  основных функций libc. Понятно, что объем С++ значительно больше.

Comment: @avp, боюсь, что c'est impossible по определению. Хотя, если мелким-премелким шрифтом и на страницах формата A4, то более-менее получится.

Comment: А жаль. Вот сейчас скачал "Дизайн и эволюция С++" (начал читать), там 450 стр. Наверняка раза в 3 можно ужать.

Comment: А это разве справочник или учебник?

Comment: Большинство хороших книг по С++ имеют объем около 1000-1500 страниц в силу того, что язык достаточно непростой, а также обладает очень большой библиотекой, и если даже из этих книг выкинуть то, что написано "для чайников" (страниц 200 от силы), то все равно сильно ужать материал не получится. А если оставить все самое-самое главное, то получится трудночитаемое нечто, по которому вы мало что сможете изучить. И вряд ли такая книга будет интересна широкому кругу читателей

Comment: Шилдт - у него хороший справочник по С++

Answer (score 5):

Могу посоветовать вам курсы лекций по С++ от INTUIT.RU, которые я в своё время приготовил для себя в удобном доковском формате. Это и не учебник для начинающего, и не просто справочник, а нечто среднее между ними, с полноценными примерами и упражнениями. Вся информация довольно структурирована, и сжата. По этой ссылке http://depositfiles.com/files/bpg0rmxe6 можно скачать архив из 18 курсов. 
(***Для заметки***: по таким курсам я изучил РНР)

Comment: Закачка, это нечто!

Comment: Буквально недавно один с их уроков по с++ видел - рекомендовали использовать iostream.h, который устарел так лет 10-15 назад.

Answer (score 3):

Вам наверняка поможет вот этот список: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).